# Changing number of rows when importing table

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I'm currently importing a table with about 17 million rows in MySQL. What catches my attention is, the number of row seems to be fluctuate.

I used the command `show table status` while my importing process was running. One time, I got 1.5 million of rows, then I ran that command again and got lower than 1.5 million. How is that possible?

Comment: Got the answer, the innodb engine only estimates the number of rows. For further explanation, please visit this (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-table-status.html)

Comment: Put your comment in as an answer and then mark it correct 24 hours later. This might help others with the same problem. I know that something similar puzzled me at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is innodb only estimates number of rows by command `show table status`. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-table-status.html for further explanation.